# How to display only those users which is related to selected customer? SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

[image]

I want to dislpay the employee which is realted to selected customer. Customer type is External.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get users which is related to which i select the external type column customer ?SharePoint 2013](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/192110/how-to-get-users-which-is-related-to-which-i-select-the-external-type-column-cus)

Comment: Dear @NadeemYousuf , should you check the provided link it's broken link "Page Not Found"

Comment: @M.Qassas, that question has been deleted by the user now. You can't see it because of less reputation.